# UIButton label not visible

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm making a custom UIButton with 2 images, but for some reason the title is just not showing up, the button is showing fine, but without any title.

```
_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 250, 300, 43);
[_button addTarget:self action:@selector(loginClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:normalButtonImg] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:hoverButtonImg] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[_button setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[_button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview:_button];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two lines:

```
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:normalButtonImg] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:hoverButtonImg] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

should be

```
[_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:normalButtonImg] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:hoverButtonImg] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Explanation: if a foreground image is set for UIButton, the image is placed above the title, so it might hide it. If you want an image **and** a title to be displayed, you have to set a *background* image.

Comment: not exactly good choice the word _ignore_. because title won't be ignored. the `image` just pushes the `title` outside of the button. when you are using a smaller image than the button size, you would see the `title` pushed to right direction by the `image`.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the image, that overrides the title. If you can make your image a background image, that will work. Otherwise you will need to create a composite image for the button by essentially creating a new image which is your desired image with the title drawn over it.